# Mapping 2D string array to Int

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the first element to an int like the following

`[["bad", ddd, 2.0, 1.0], ["great",ddd , 3.0, 1.0], ["fair",ddd , 4.0, 1.0], ["great",ddd , 5.0, 1.0]]`

↓

`[[0, ddd, 2.0, 1.0], [2,ddd , 3.0, 1.0], [1,ddd , 4.0, 1.0], [2,ddd , 5.0, 1.0]]`

what is the best way to do this? I have tried to use map but have no success.

Comment: first element is the array is the index of the array?  
I'm confused 0, 2, 1, 2 data

Comment: I looked at it, first element seems to be a value you don't show what determines it in your question. Considering your rep I dont know why you dont include how the first element should be determined on output?

Comment: What makes `"bad"` become 0, what makes `"great"` become 2? Perhaps show your *I have tried to use map but have no success.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set("bad", 0);
map.set("great", 2);
map.set("fair", 1);

const param = [["bad", 'zzz', 2.0, 1.0], ["great",'ddd' , 3.0, 1.0], ["fair",'ddd' , 4.0, 1.0], ["great",'ddd6' , 5.0, 1.0]];

param.map(([a,b,c,d]) => {
    return [map.get(a), b, c, d];
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! this was exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

`ddd` is string, so `"ddd"`. `ratings` is a filtering array, when a match is found with `.indexOf()` it returns an index number:

```
sub[0] = ratings.indexOf(sub[0]);
```

```js
// Utility function
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

const data = [
  ["bad", 'ddd', 2.0, 1.0],
  ["great", 'ddd', 3.0, 1.0],
  ["fair", 'ddd', 4.0, 1.0],
  ["great", 'ddd', 5.0, 1.0]
];
const ratings = ["bad", "fair", "great"];

const result = data.map(sub => {
  sub[0] = ratings.indexOf(sub[0]);
  return sub;
});

log(result);
```